# Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed on Strings?

Tags: algorithm, hash, md5, unique, sha

Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed on Strings?

I know there are things like SHA-*, MD5 and such,  I want a hash algorithm designed to be fast,  unique and safe.

Comment: Damn! I knew a good one that's slow, unsafe with lots of collision ;-)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed

Comment: Given that there's an infinite number of possible strings and a finite number of possible 32-byte hashes, your uniqueness criterion is unrealistic.

Comment: md5 and sha are very slow since their main property  is security, not performance: one bit change in source causes appx 50% bits change in hash!

Answer (score 3):

You have a nice post on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) with pros and cons on each hash function: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed